# string substituton for match pattern

Tags: sed, sql

I have an SQL file of 170GB. I am trying to restore it on AWS RDS but i am not able because of keyring encryption is enabled on the file. I can't edit it using vi because it's causing my session timedout.

I am trying to do this activity with sed command but i am not able to.

This is command i am using but string value is not changing.

```
 sed -i 's/ENCRYPTION='Y'/ENCRYPTION='N'/g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use single quotes in a single quoted string.

Instead, use double quotes around the `sed` expression:

```
sed -i "s/ENCRYPTION='Y'/ENCRYPTION='N'/g"
```

I doubt this would magically decrypt your data, but it's at least replacing the strings in the file the way you probably intended.

---

Your original command tried to replace `ENCRYPTION=Y` with `ENCRYPTION=N` (note the missing single quotes).  This is because the initial single quote in `'Y'` 
ends the string `s/ENCRYPTION=`. You then concatenate an unquoted `Y` with this followed by the single quoted string `/ENCRYPTION=` followed by an unquoted `N` and the single quoted string `/g`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works

Comment: *You can't use single quotes in a single quoted string.*  True.  but you **can** end the quoted string, add an escaped quote, and then start single-quoting again (`'\''`).  e.g.   `sed -i 's/ENCRYPTION='\''Y'\''/ENCRYPTION='\''N'\''/g'`.   using double quotes is easier, of course. but then you need to remember to escape `$` and other meta-characters.