# Replace text in big file using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, large-files

I have a big file that contains a text will be replaced based on a regular expression passed to.
The regular expression is tested and can find matching pattern, but when I use it with `sed` no text replaced.
Note that my environment is Windows, and I have 16GB memory, file size is ~14GB.

```
sed -i "/,[\r\n]+  CONSTRAINT `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` FOREIGN KEY \(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`\) REFERENCES `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` \(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`\)/ s// /g" all_files_test.sql
```

(note that the above is a `cmd.exe` command line, not a Unix shell one).

`all_files_test.sql` file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `holdings_FLZWHX`;
;
;
CREATE TABLE `holdings_FLZWHX` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateAdded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `FundId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AssetId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DayChangeEqt` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PMinDayRet` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_FundId` (`FundId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_AssetId` (`AssetId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_TypeId` (`TypeId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_TickerId` (`TickerId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_StyleId` (`StyleId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_SectorId` (`SectorId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_CountryId` (`CountryId`),
  KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_CurrencyId` (`CurrencyId`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FundId`) REFERENCES `target_funds` (`fundid`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`AssetId`) REFERENCES `asset` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`TypeId`) REFERENCES `type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`TickerId`) REFERENCES `ticker` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`StyleId`) REFERENCES `style` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`SectorId`) REFERENCES `sector` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryId`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `holdings_FLZWHX_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`CurrencyId`) REFERENCES `currency` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4201 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
;
```

The result I was expecting:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `holdings_FLZWHX`;
;
;
CREATE TABLE `holdings_FLZWHX` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateAdded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `FundId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AssetId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DayChangeEqt` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PMinDayRet` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4201 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
;
```

Comment: try `sed '/CONSTRAINT/d;/  KEY/d' all_files_test.sql`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532869/string-substituton-for-match-pattern Check this link. It's because of the quotes.

Comment: But I need the full pattern I set.

Comment: Note that `[\r\n]+` matches on either a backslash `r` or `n` followed by a `+`. `sed` regexps are basic regexps by default. In any case, `sed` works on one line at a time so what it matches on will never contain a newline character.

Comment: It is a `cmd.exe`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Using the `-i` option without extension argument indicates that the OP is using either GNU `sed` or busybox `sed`, so `[\r\n]` will match either CR or LF. However, you are right about the fact, that there can't be newlines inside one line.

Comment: @Philippos, also by NetBSD and OpenBSD sed and note that GNU `sed`'s behaviour in that regard depends on how GNU sed was compiled and whether `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment, but you're right, since the OP's on MS Windows, their sed is most probably one port or another of GNU sed with included regexps and `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is unlikely to be in the environment, so `[\r\n]` is likely to only match on CR.

Comment: @HAßdøµ How do you expect the ```KEY `holdings_FLZWHX_``` ... lines to disappear with your given command? What is the rule?

Answer (score 2):

1. *The regular expression is tested* is a difficult statement, as there is not only basic and extended regular expressions, but also a number of non-standard flavours, some of which you are using.
2. You are using extended regular expressions, you you need to tell your `sed` with option `-E`
3. You are looking for line breaks (carriage return, line feed) in your pattern, but `sed` does process the input line by line, so this will never match unless you join lines. However, you seem to be using GNU `sed`, so you have the `-z` option to process all lines at once. This works for the example, but is likely to fail for huge files.
4. Depending on your shell, you may need to use single quotes instead of double quotes to protect the script.

   sed -zEi '/,[\r\n]+  CONSTRAINT `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` FOREIGN KEY (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`) REFERENCES `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`)/ s// /g' all_files_test.sql

already does the replacing you are expecting in `zsh`, maybe also in your `cmd.exe`. Still, the line address is nonsense with all lines in one buffer, so

```
sed -zEi 's/,[\r\n]+  CONSTRAINT `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` FOREIGN KEY \(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`\) REFERENCES `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` \(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`\)/ /g' all_files_test.sql
```

is more logical (the result remains the same). Finally, you don't explain how you expect the `` KEY `holding `` lines to disappear.

But now to a standard way to do multi-line substitution, the `N;P;D` pattern, which should also work for huge files:

```
sed -Ei 'N;/,*[\r\n]+  CONSTRAINT `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` FOREIGN KEY \(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`\) REFERENCES `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` \(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`\)/{s// /g;s/^/\n/;D;};P;D' all_files_test.sql
```

`N` always appends the next line, so your pattern can match. `P` prints the first line of the buffer and `D` removes that first line and starts over with the rest. So with `N;P;D` you always have a pair of lines in the pattern space.

However, if we did replace, we have only one line, but want to continue with the next one, so the trick is to insert an empty line at the beginning of the pattern with `s/^/\n/` (GNU `sed` only!) to get removed by the `D`.